# Searching for a way to play a time series of quiver-plots

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I have a number of frames from a video sequence that I use to estimate optical flow fields in between:

```
[u, v] = compute_optical_flow(series);
```

I can play the video sequence using `implay`:

```
implay(series);
```

And I can plot a single flow on top of a single image using `quiver`:

```
imshow(series(123,:,:));
hold on;
quiver(u(123,:,:), v(123,:,:));
```

However, I also want to be able to play the whole time series of velocity-vectors stored in u and v (if possible on top of the corresponding image frames). So what I am looking for is `implay` but for velocity fields instead of images.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple hack is to use the `pause` MATLAB function. You code should look something like this:

```
framesPerSecond = 30;

for n = 1:N %# Here N is the number of frames you have
    imshow(series(n,:,:));
    hold on;
    quiver(u(n,:,:), v(n,:,:));
    hold off;
    pause(1/framesPerSecond);
end
```